# using jsch( JCraft) i need to pg a unix text file

Tags: java, ssh

i need to connect to ssh server and pull out data of a huge file.
iam able to do it with cat command , and it takes nearly 10 -15 mins time.

The challange here is, i cant user sftp , exe 
i.e Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp"); &  Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");  not allowed in my prd environment.

The only option left behind is "shell".

Can anyone tell me how to do pg , until a specific pattern is found in the file.

Please help me with a code example !!

Hope you got my query . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about following sample program?

```
 https://gist.github.com/4482587
```

It will remotely exec "gzip -c", and gunzip the given data stream.

Comment: thanks dear ymnk , in my PRD environment i have no right to execute gzip command. only possible to get file content is CAT command or PG Command. CAT command takes more time so wanted to go for PG command , so kindly help to know how can i try PG cmd until certain pattern is found...thnks!!

Comment: If "PG command" means pg command(browse pagewise through text files), I don't have an idea to use it for that purpose.

How about enabling the packet compression? After adding jzlib.jar to the CLASSPATH, try https://gist.github.com/4482587#file-foo-java 

jzlib.jar will be available at http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.jcraft%7Cjzlib%7C1.1.1%7Cjar